# Disable PyQt Arrow Key Focus

Tags: python, pyqt, overriding, arrow-keys

I have a very simple PyQt application with some buttons and a checkbox.

Right now pressing the arrow keys iterates focus over the buttons and the checkbox. I would like to override the arrow keys events and instead have it print which key you pressed, so pressing "right" would print "right" instead of changing the focus to the next component.

It looks like pressing the arrow keys generates a Paint QEvent and not a KeyPress event so they do not get caught.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Overriding QWidget::keyPressEvent()?

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear as to exactly what you are trying to achieve, but without any additional information, I would try setting the focus policy of the buttons and checkboxes, e.g.:

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton('button1')
button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```